# How to create sequence which start from 1 in each day

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

Sequence should return values 1,2,3 etc starting for 1 for every day.
current_date should used for day determination.

For example, calling today first time it shoudl return 1, in second time 2 etc.

Tomorrow, first call shoud return again 1, second call 2 etc.

Postgres 9.1 is used.

Comment: You can schedule a job to reset the sequence.  Or, if this is a column in a table, then you can calculate it on the output.

Comment: Maybe plpgsql procedure can created which checks for first call in day and resets sequence. How to place lock  during this so that concurrent calls to this method are serialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a table to keep the sequence:

```
create table daily_sequence (
    day date, s integer, primary key (day, s)
);
```

This function will retrieve the next value:

```
create or replace function daily_sequence()
returns int as $$
    insert into daily_sequence (day, s)
    select current_date, coalesce(max(s), 0) + 1
    from daily_sequence
    where day = current_date
    returning s
    ;
$$ language sql;

select daily_sequence();
```

Be prepared to retry in case of an improbable `duplicate key value` error. If previous days' sequences are not necessary delete them to keep the table and the index as light as possible:

```
create or replace function daily_sequence()
returns int as $$
    with d as (
        delete from daily_sequence
        where day < current_date
    )
    insert into daily_sequence (day, s)
    select current_date, coalesce(max(s), 0) + 1
    from daily_sequence
    where day = current_date
    returning s
    ;
$$ language sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to think of cronjob as running a shell command at a specified time or day.

Shell Command for running cron job
psql --host host.domain.com --port 32098 --db_name databaseName < my.sql

You can then just add this to your crontab (I recommend you use crontab -e to avoid breaking things)

```
# It will run your command at 00:00 every day
# min hour wday month mday command-to-run
    0    0    *     *    * psql --host host.domain.com --port 32098 --db_name databaseName < my.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite interesting task.

Lets try to use additional sequence for the date and alternative function to get next value:

```
-- We will use anonymous block here because it is impossible to use
-- variables and functions in DDL directly 
do language plpgsql $$
begin
  execute 'create sequence my_seq_day start with ' || (current_date - '1900-01-01')::varchar;
end; $$;

-- Initialize sequence
select nextval('my_seq_day');

create sequence my_seq;

create or replace function nextval_daily(in p_seq varchar) returns bigint as $$
declare
  dd bigint;
  lv bigint;
begin
  select current_date - '1900-01-01'::date into dd;
  -- Here we should to retrieve current value from sequence
  -- properties instead of currval function to make it session-independent 
  execute 'select last_value from '||p_seq||'_day' into lv;
  if dd - lv > 0 then
    -- If next day has come
    -- Reset main sequens
    execute 'alter sequence '||p_seq||' restart';
    -- And set the day sequence to the current day
    execute 'alter sequence '||p_seq||'_day restart with '||dd::varchar;
    execute 'select nextval('''||p_seq||'_day'')' into lv;
  end if;
  return nextval(p_seq);
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

Then use function `nextval_daily` instead of `nextval`.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: very nice and clean :)

Answer (score 0):

I have  came across with almost similar requirement.

Handled the logic from query rather than modifying the sequence.
used **setval()** to reset the sequence to **0** if its the first entry to the table for the day.
Else  **nextval()** of the sequence.

Below is the sample query :

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
SELECT   primary_key   FROM    schema.table   WHERE   date(updated_datetime) = #{systemDate} limit 1)
THEN 
setval('scheam.job_seq', 1) 
ELSE 
nextval('scheam.job_seq') 
END
```

**UPDATE** privilege is required for the user to execute setval.

```
GRANT UPDATE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA ur_schema TO user;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by Clodoaldo Neto's answers and wrote a script for my project.
You can copy it for yourself and use it immediately, just don’t forget to change names and comments that are relevant to your project.

```
create sequence if not exists daily_sequence start 1 increment 1;
comment on sequence daily_sequence is 'The sequence which reset every day';

create table last_reset_date_table
(
    last_reset_date date not null
);

comment on table last_reset_date_table is 'The table keeps the last reset date of daily_sequence';

insert into last_reset_date_table (last_reset_date)
values (current_date);

comment on column last_reset_date_table.last_reset_date is 'The last reset date of daily_sequence';

create
    or replace function daily_sequence()
    returns integer as
$$
declare
    v_last_reset_date date;
begin
    -- Select the last reset date 'for the update' to lock the row
    select last_reset_date
    into v_last_reset_date
    from last_reset_date_table for update;

    -- Check if the last reset date is today
    if
            v_last_reset_date != current_date then
        -- Reset the sequence
        perform setval('daily_sequence', 1, false);
        -- Update the last reset date to today
        update last_reset_date_table
        set last_reset_date = current_date
        where last_reset_date != current_date;
    end if;
    return nextval('daily_sequence');
end;
$$
    language plpgsql;
```