# Race condition when two different users inserting new records to database in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, race-condition

There is a **race condition** situation, when I want to create a new instance of model `Order`.
There is a `daily_id` field that everyday for any category starts from one. It means every category has its own daily id.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    daily_id = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categoty, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="orders")
    declare_time = models.DateField()
    ...
}
```

`daily_id` field of new record is being calculated using this method:

```
def get_daily_id(category, declare_time):
    try:
        last_order = Order.objects.filter(declare_time=declare_time,
                                          category=category).latest('daily_id')
        return last_order.daily_id + 1
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        # If no order has been registered in declare_time date.
        return 1
```

The problem is that when two different users are registering orders in the same category at the same time, it is highly likely that the orders have the repetitive `daily_id` values.

I have tried `@transaction.atomic` decorator for `post` method of DRF APIView and it didn't work!

Comment: By using an `AutoField`, the database will dispatch ids, and these are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Is that possible to reset AutoField on the given conditions? (everyday for each category)

Comment: Unless there is a hard requirements for numbering that way I would strongly suggest to just not do that as it is not good for performance. If you must the best solution is to make a unique constraint on day, category and the daily_id in the database. If you get a duplicate key error while storing determine new value for daily_id and try to store again.

Comment: Why do you reset an id? You can count the number of orders and categories per day even without an id.

Comment: Obviously `AutoField` solution does not work. User can also update the order's category and `daily_id` needs to be updated with the last id of new category + 1. So there is no other option than applied solution. @Eelke

Comment: @FrankHeikens orders can be deleted, then counting them is not a good idea.

Comment: @AminA2: I don't get it: When you delete an order, you can't count that order anymore because it's not an order. That works fine. And if you still want to keep the original order, just change the status of this order to "deleted" or something like that and just count the orders that are not deleted. Also works fine. And no reset needed.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Image the last order's daily_id is 30, now order 20 is being deleted. Next order's daily id would be 30 again.  :)

Comment: @FrankHeikens And your solution will not solve the race condition situation. The orders count can be the same for two different users requesting at the same time.

Comment: Who cares that order 20 is deleted? Your sequence just gives you a number and that's it. Who cares what number it is? It should be unique, but that's it. And when the last sequence number was number 30, the next one will be number 31. That's how a sequence works. You can have hundreds of concurrent orders and they all get unique numbers.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I suppose there is a misunderstanding. Just to elaborate, Your solution was counting orders per category for each day, right? What I'm saying is that suppose there are 29 orders. The next order's daily_id would be 30. Now we have 30 orders. If an order is being deleted, there are 29 orders again and the next daily_id would be 30 again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Id in Django Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724712/custom-id-in-django-models)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for your response, but I don't think this is the standard way of solving this issue.

Comment: @AminA2 there is no standard way Django currently gives to solve this issue. That answer is one of the ways I can think of that will work on multiple databases. Another way I can think of (but will be specific to databases) is to create a table similar to that answer and then instead of handling the value in python, create a database function (using a migration) that will handle the value somewhat like shown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510370/how-to-create-sequence-which-start-from-1-in-each-day and use that function to compute the value of the column

Answer (score 0):

You must use an auto increment and add a view that computes your semantic order like :

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MyDayDate ORDER BY id_autoinc) AS daily_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution I'm looking for should prevent the race condition I've encountered. I will try your approach if that didn't work.

Comment: this solution prevent the race condition beacause there is no race conditions in a view that's only reads